# GWT Entry point Configuration

Tags: gwt, registration, entry-point

Hi
I have to create one login module using GWT with RPC with the functionality of login, registration and forgotPassword. Login is working fine. Now i have to proceed for registration and forgot password but i have in trouble to configure entry point. In my login page i have created hyperlink "REGISTER" and "FORGOT PASSWORD" and when i will click on Register Hyperlink i want to open Registration page (created using GWT) but i have no idea to implement that. please provide me any useful suggestion..

Thanks
**Arun**

Comment: Do You want to inject these pages to some div on your page, when user cliks register link, or do you want to open new page?

Comment: i want to inject these pages to some div on page.

Answer (score 0):

You can create [Hyperlink](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Hyperlink.html) objects that have tokens for example Register and forgotPassword. Then you add a HistoryListener or a ValueChangeHandler (depends on which version of GWT you are using) and then just add the page to the panel or if you want to do a redirect you can do a JSNI redirect.

```
public static native void redirect(String url)/*-{
        $wnd.location = url;
    }-*/;
```

[Docs for GWT 2.0](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html)

Comment: I didn't get it how to use it..Please describe or provide me some small example.